# how to Find the period of complex exponential function?

Tags: signal-processing, periodic-functions

How we can find period of this sequence?

$x[n]= e^{jn2π/3}$

Is it equal to   $T=2π/(2π/3) $  or  not?

I mean relation $T=2π/\omega$   will be valid in this case or not?

Comment: thanks jose carlos

Answer (score 1):

The sequence $x[n]=e^{jn2\pi/3}$ is actually a discrete complex exponential sequence. One thing to keep in mind is that the values of $n$ will always be an integer and never a fraction. To find the period of a discrete sequence we can use the fact that,
$$x[n+N]=x[n]$$
where $N \gt 0$, and the $N$ is the least positive integer for which the sequence repeats itself.
That is to say, since $x[n]$ is periodic with period $N$ it repeats itself after $N$ samples. And it is also periodic with the period $2N$,$3N$,$4N$, and so on so we choose the smallest possible positive integer $N$. So:
$$e^{j(n+N)2\pi/3}=e^{jn2\pi/3}$$
Solving you will get,$$e^{jN2\pi/3}=1$$
$$\cos(\frac{2N\pi}{3})+ j\sin(\frac{2N\pi}{3})=1+j0$$

$$\cos(\frac{2N\pi}{3}) =1=\cos 0,\cos2\pi,\cos4\pi...$$
Or,
$$\sin(\frac{2N\pi}{3}) =0=\sin 0,\sin2\pi,\sin4\pi...$$
Both are same. We will choose the value $2\pi$ because the period should be positive and least.
So,
$$\frac{2N\pi}{3}=2\pi$$
giving you $$N=3$$
So the period is $N$, now you can also see why the formula $$T=\frac{2\pi}{\omega}$$ actually works.Graphically this sequence can be plotted as a continuous sinusoid sampled at 1 second,  Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

$e^{jn2\pi / 3} = cos(2n\pi/3) + i\cdot sin(2 n \pi/3)$ From there, it is easy to see that the period is $\frac{2 \pi}{2\pi/3} = 3$

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, as the complex exponent have the properties:
$$
e^{z_1+z_2}=e^{z_1}e^{z_2},\text{ and }e^{2\pi i}=1.
$$

Consider now the function:
$$
f(x)=e^{i2\pi\frac xT},
$$
where $T\in\mathbb R$.

Can you find the relation between $f(x)$ and $f(x+T)$? Can you link the result to your particular function?

PS. I have used $i$ for $\sqrt{-1}$.

Comment: e^2πi=1      i can't understand it ?and how it is applicabile to this question?

Comment: @student How do you understand $e^{ix}$  in general? $e^{z+2\pi i}=e^{z}e^{2\pi i}=e^{z}\cdot1=?$